# aspnet_regiis -i needs admin rights

Tags: windows, iis-7

I'm trying to run asp_net regiis -i from the command prompt in my framework directory.  My user account is set to administrator but, when I run the command, the error tells me:

"You must have administrative rights on this machine in order to run this tool".

I tried to create another account with admin permissions which I can't do.  When I try I get the error that the username I use doesn't exist.  Which, of course, it doesn't.  That's the point, I'm trying to create it.  Besides, I'm not even sure it'll work.

Either way, the crux of it is I have an administrator's account to run aspnet_regiis tool but the command prompt indicates that I don't.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I chose 'Run as Administrator' after right clicking Command Prompt.

Comment: This was a problem I had and this answer had solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

You should run asp_net regiis as administrator to encrypt/decrypt configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

Start -> cmd, rightclick on it and select "Run as Administrator". It will confirm, click yes, and you will get a command prompt open.

Now navigate to the folder where asp_net regiis is residing... and execute the command "asp_net regiis -i"

Hope this helps.